# how can I make a docker container run a command that will restart another container

Tags: docker, container

I made a fastAPI docker container, and it's running fine, unless 1 command...
I need it to restart another docker container when some event happen.

I have a server[host], running docker, docker is running containerA (fastAPI) and containerB ...
How can I make containerA run a command that will make the host execute this command:

> docker restart containerB

Note, the host OS is linux.

I tried to use python's subprocess.run() , but it didn't work of course , containerA doesn't have docker installed, so of course it has no docker commands.
I've read articles saying that mounting unix socket will work, I tried mounting '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock' but it didn't work as well.

If you have an idea how to make it work, I'd be grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: Mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` is indeed the usual approach for this; what didn’t work in your case?

Comment: I simply got "subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['docker', 'restart', 'v2fly']' returned non-zero exit status 127."
It didn't found "docker" command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` inside the container is the usual approach for this, as long as you’re comfortable [exposing your host’s Docker daemon to the container](https://blog.quarkslab.com/why-is-exposing-the-docker-socket-a-really-bad-idea.html). For this to work, you also need to ensure the Docker client binary (`docker`) is available inside the container; in your case it isn’t, you need to add it to the image.

Comment: This is not the docker's recommended way. Mine is.

Comment: I explained what the caveat is.

Comment: Both give me insights to possible solutions...  to install docker client to container you mean "RUN apt install docker-ce" inside the container? Or something else?

Comment: @AbdAlhaleemBakkor `apt install docker.io` if you’re using a Debian base image (or a derivative), `dnf install moby-engine` if you’re using a Fedora base image (or a derivative).

Comment: problem solved, it worked using after installing docker.io

Answer (score 1):

This would be a better design to mount bind a directory, then create a file on the mount between host and container, and from host look changes on this directory, then restart docker container.

To bind mount, as usual from host:

```
docker run ... -v /host/path:/container/path:rw
```

On host, check directory:

```
while true; do
    if test -e "$dir/test"; then
        docker restart containerX
        rm -f "$dir/test"
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

From the container:

```
touch "$dir/test"
```

---

[image: warning]

Even if it's technically possible to share the docker's socket to run docker commands inside containers, docker's experts suggest to not do because of security reasons.

---

[Read about DooD and DinD](https://blog.nestybox.com/2019/09/14/dind.html#docker-in-docker-approaches), maybe `podman` is better for security if you insist to use that approach. `podman` don't have a root service running like `docker`.

Comment: you mean making the container execute a shell script? 
 I'ts still the same the container doesn't have a docker installed..  It's not about mounting a volume, I already know how to do that, it's about restarting a container running on the host machine.

Comment: Added example. Read again

Comment: I see, but is there any better way to do it? 
I hate endless loops, many things could go wrong there, and it's a waste of resources.

Comment: This is just an example, you could use `inotifywait` (from `inotify-tools`) to trigger actions on changes...